# how to pass argument in cakephp requestAction?

Tags: php, url, cakephp, url-routing

anyone can tell me, how to pass arguments in cakephp $this->requestAction(...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
requestAction(string $url, array $options)
```

This function calls a controller's action from any location and returns data from the action. The $url passed is a CakePHP-relative `URL (/controllername/actionname/params)`. To pass extra data to the receiving controller action add to the $options array.

```
# echo $this->requestAction('/articles/view/5');
```

Comment: not working means, is it throwing any error? post if any error occured

Comment: # echo $this->requestAction('/articles/view/5', array('return'));
This is correct!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
$url = Router::url(array(
    'controller' => 'Foo',
    'action' => 'edit',
    3
));
$this->requestAction($url);
```