# Passing array to requestAction in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have function

```
public myfunction($myArray) {
}
```

I need to pass `array("cat", "dog")`   To action.

```
$output = $this->requestAction(
    array('controller' => 'app', 'action' => 'myfunction'),
    array("cat","dog")
);
```

But this passes only `cat` to my controller action, `dog` wasn't passed.

I tried this:

```
$output = $this->requestAction(
    array('controller' => 'app', 'action' => 'myfunction'),
    array("myArray" => array("cat","dog"))
);
```

But it didn't help. I checked [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3arequestAction) but couldn't find relevant example.
How can I fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code

```
$this->requestAction(
    array('controller' => 'app', 'action' => 'myfunction'),
        array('pass' => array('dog','cat'))
            );
```

in Myfunction :

```
public myfunction() {
    pr($this->params->params['pass']);
}
```

Tell me if not working...

Comment: That works well you saved my day. I couldn't find anything about this from cookbook..

Answer (score 2):

see tho url

http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/991/requestAction

[how to pass argument in cakephp requestAction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524863/how-to-pass-argument-in-cakephp-requestaction)

try this

```
$option = array("cat_dog"); 

$this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'app', 'action' => 'myfunction'), $option);
```

after then get $option array and explode it.

```
$myArray = explode('_', your get variable); 

pr($myArray);
```

Comment: I need to pass an array to action. "return" is not an array?

Comment: try this echo $this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'app', 'action' => 'myfunction'), array('return', 'param' => array("cat","dog"))));

Comment: cakephp which ver you have to use

Comment: requestAction(string $url, array $options)

try this                                                                              
$option =  array("cat","dog");
$this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'app', 'action' => 'myfunction'), array(return),$option);

Comment: Last line didn't work. Also **array("return"),$option** didn't work

Comment: try this $option = array("cat","dog"); $this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'app', 'action' => 'myfunction'), array(),$option);

Comment: Nope :( Errors are: Warning (2): Missing argument 
Notice (8): Undefined variable: myArray

Comment: try this $option = array("cat","dog"); $this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'app', 'action' => 'myfunction'), $option);

Comment: This was my first option. **cat** is passed but **dog** didn't passed.

Comment: try this

$option = array("cat_dog");

$this->requestAction(array('controller' => 'app', 'action' => 'myfunction'), $option);

after then

get $option array and explode it.

$myArray = explode('_', your get variable);

pr($myArray);

Comment: I Think this is an awesome solution @AbidHussain

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$output = $this->requestAction(
array('controller' => 'app', 'action' => 'myfunction'),
array("animals" => array("cat"=>"cat","dog"=>"dog"))
);
```