# Cakephp 2.3: How to send an array of data to an action in another controller for rendering?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a controller action that is supposed to validate the data and pass the results (array of data) to an action in another controller for further processing. I don't want to use Session Component for this as this is not considered ideal. Given that, is there any other way to pass data array to another controller/action.

I am using CakePHP 2.3.10

Because of the length of the data array, I am not sure if I could send as namedParams or Query string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ideal (and for me correct) approach is to not redirect at all. The same action - and at some point the model layer - can process the data - directly and without more complication.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should be able to use the requestAction, have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11752642/191998

Comment: requestAction should be a last resort for performance reasons. Would be useful to see some code to see if there are alternative ways to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using uses as shown in the example below:

```
 App::uses('AnotherController','Controller');
    class ContentsController extends AppController {

      function youAction(){
         $anotherControllerObject = new AnotherController();
         $anotherControllerObject->anotherControllerfunction($longDataArray);

      }
    }
```

Comment: This may be the right approach for me. Let me try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the majority of what you need to do in ControllerA is validation and massaging the data. This can be handled by the Model attached to it.

If you move the logic from controllerA to a function in ModelA, you can then just cut out ControllerA by passing the data straight to ControllerB and having ControllerB access ModelA using loadModel.

For example in ControllerB:

```
$this->loadModel('ModelA');
$validatedData = $this->ModelA->aDataProcessingFunction($this->request->data);

//continue with second step of processing
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. My need is different. I have two different controllers handling dedicated work process (Say, CustomersController and Products Controller) Each of these controllers handle specific related functions/rending.

Comment: I wish I could add more here. But this site is not allowing me to. My need is different though. I have two different controllers handling dedicated work process (Say, Customers Controller and Products Controller) Each of these controllers handle specific related functions/rending. In my situation, CustomersController does it's job first (after user post) and depending on the data provided by the user, this CustomersController has to pass the data (User Supplied as well as it's own generated data) to Products Controller so that Products Controller can continue with remaining + Prod Rendering.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a controller action that is supposed to validate the data and
>   pass the results (array of data) to an action in another controller
>   for further processing.

Why not keep the further processing in Model (embrace fat model).